# Why does VSCode suddenly fail to suggest variable names from other files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

As soon as VSCode updated to version 1.79.0 (on 2023-06-10 for me), it stopped suggesting variable names from other files. Everything was working fine up to yesterday.

I recreated the simplest example I could:
[image: gif showcasing the bug]

What went wrong? Is there a new setting I need to change? Or is there a way to downgrade?

Comment: You not using any type of module loading?, If not you might need a `tsconfig` or `jsconfig` to let VS know.  Maybe the default for module resolution changed.